# How to compare data from 2 files then create an output file that has the missing data in the order of file 2

Tags: text-processing, awk

I'm new to shell scripting and would like to create the below. I believe I could use something like `grep -xvFf file1 file2` but I'm not sure how to create output file with the correct order.

I have file1 as below:

```
CustomerName     CustomerID
Joe                  1
Kenny                2
Craig                3
Pearl                4
```

file2 has below:

```
CustomerName      CustomerID
Pearl
Kenny
Joe
Craig
```

So what I am trying to accomplish is creating a comparison of the two files to find the missing data then output that data in a third file with the same order as file2. So the output file would look like the below:

```
CustomerName      CustomerID
Pearl                 4
Kenny                 2
Joe                   1
Craig                 3
```

Any Insight would be wonderful

Comment: What about customer names that are in file2 but not file1 and vice-versa?

Answer (score 3):

Use `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==1 { print; }
     NR==FNR && FNR>1{ customerIds[$1]=$2; next }
     FNR>1 && ($1 in customerIds) { print $1, customerIds[$1]; }
' OFS='\t' file1 file2
```

print the header line once when with `NR==1 { print; }`.
then store the customer Ids from the *file1* into an associated array called `customerIds` (keys are customerName `$1`, values are the Ids `$2`) with:

```
NR==FNR && FNR>1{ customerIds[$1]=$2; next }
```

next we checks on *file2*, if the customerName was exist in the `customerIds` array then print the customerName `$1` followed by their Ids from the same array we were saved above.

```
FNR>1 && ($1 in customerIds) { print $1, customerIds[$1]; }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0; next} $1 in a{print a[$1]}' file1 file2
CustomerName     CustomerID
Pearl                4
Kenny                2
Joe                  1
Craig                3
```

Comment: Thanks everyone. I will try both suggestions and respond this evening.